# How to add external data store to AWS Glue Crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

For a new crawler, I want to extract data from an external MySQL database which I can access remotely using the host, username and password. In Glue, I am stuck with configuring the data store. JDBC seems close however, it requires VPC security group and subnet which I do not have given the fact that the database is external (not in the same AWS account I am using).

Is there a way around this or maybe something I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with a few days ago when with a lambda/step function situation I found your question. It turns out that glue crawlers requires a VPC configuration + security group to connect to an external database.

If the external database that you are referring is an AWS RDS MySQL but from another AWS Account you can use VPC peering to connect one VPC account to another and allow traffic between the two. When creating a new crawler you will indicate the VPC that has the connection with the external Database.

If the database it's on-premises then the workaround is a little more complicated since it also require a VPN connection. More details can be found in the following article below.

[https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/]

Hopefully that can help you a little!